# Laravel eloquent restrict withCount with whereHas or another

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I have 3 models `Supplier`, `Purchase` and `PurchaseDetail`.
To join the Supplier model with PurchaseDetail through Purchase I have created a hasManyThrough relation.

`hasManyThrough` inside `Supplier` model:

```php
public function detail_purchases(){
    return $this->hasManyThrough(PurchaseDetail::class, Purchase::class);
}
```

The relationship works well and I can count the quantities purchased from sellers as follows:

```php
$collectors = Supplier::withCount(['detail_purchases as qty_sold' => function($query) {
    return $query->select(\DB::raw('SUM(qty)'))
        ->where('unit', '=', 'kg');
}])
    ->where('supplier_type','=','persona_natural')
    ->orderBy('qty_sold','desc')
    ->get();
```

SQL Query output:

```sql
select `suppliers`.*, (
    select SUM(qty)
    from `purchase_details`
    inner join `purchases` on `purchases`.`id` = `purchase_details`.`purchase_id`
    where `suppliers`.`id` = `purchases`.`supplier_id`
        and `unit` = 'kg'
        and `purchases`.`deleted_at` is null
) as `qty_sold`
from `suppliers`
where `supplier_type` = 'persona_natural'
order by `qty_sold` desc;
```

Output rows:

[image]

My problem is that this query is bringing me sellers that I did not make purchases from them, I don't know why they infiltrate the query if it is assumed that the hasManyThrough relationship only joins those who are registered in Purchase or made purchases from them.

Also the `Supplier` model has another relation called `purchases`:

```php
public function purchases() {
    return $this->hasMany(Purchase::class, 'supplier_id');
}
```

And the model `Purchase` has a relation hasMany with PurchaseDetail :

```php
public function details(){
    return $this->hasMany(PurchaseDetail::class, 'purchase_id');
}
```

[image]

**Updated**

Using whereHas now I can get all the suppliers that I did purchases however the qty_sold is not appearing in the results:

```php
$collectors =  Supplier::whereHas('purchases', function($query){
    $query->withCount(['details as qty_sold' => function($query){
        $query->select(\DB::raw('SUM(qty)'))
            ->where('unit', '=', $this->unit);
        }]);
    })
    ->where('supplier_type','=','persona_natural')
    ->get();
```

This selection is important because I want to know how many `kgs` of all products I purchased.

Comment: Get the SQL query executed by replacing `->get()` with `->toSql()` and post the result in your question. It might help to understand why the other suppliers are being included.

Comment: Hi @Tony I have updated my question, Check it.. this is  throwing all the suppliers..

Comment: @Tony I have updated, see and the end. The whereHas is working but the SUM isn't appearing in the results.

Comment: In your updated query can you move the `withCount` out of the subquery? So you would have `Supplier::withCount(...)->whereHas('purchases')...`
The other thing I do when trying to build a more complex query is to write it out in SQL and then start translating that to a PDO query, and then to Eloquent. It also helps to build the query up bit-by-bit: start with retrieving the correct rows and then do the aggregation.

Comment: Looking at your first query, it was selecting all suppliers and then performing a sub-query to get the counts, because the table joins using your `hasManyThrough` table were only in the subquery.

Comment: Please ensure your code is properly formatted when posting. There's no reason to have 30 spaces before a line of code, or to have lines with 500 characters in them.

Comment: @Tony I fixed it, thanks. miken32 I will do next time.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to  @Tony

> In your updated query can you move the withCount out of the subquery? So you would have Supplier::withCount(...)->whereHas('purchases')..

I fixed it, adding first the `whereHas` directive the I used the `hasManyThrough`
relation with `withCount`. Of this way only suppliers that has purchases are selected.

```
 $collectors = Supplier::whereHas('purchases')
   ->withCount([
     'detail_purchases as qty_sold' => function($query){
       $query->select(\DB::raw('SUM(qty)'))
         ->where('unit', '=', 'kg');
     }
   ])
   ->where('supplier_type','=', 'persona_natural')
   ->get();
```

Comment: Good to hear you got it working